# How do I change basic information, profile picture, etc. for a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a page in Facebook for a website I own. I am the admin for the page, but I am unable to change the page info, picture, etc. How do I enable those options?  If I am unable to restore these options, is it possible to delete the page (has a custom vanity URL) and then create a new page with the same custom vanity URL?

This is what the *Edit Page* looks like:

[image: Restricted Facebook page admin]

As you can see, the following sections are missing from the edit page:

- Your Settings
- Basic Information
- Profile Picture
- Featured

Comment: How long ago was this page setup? Did you go through the getting started steps?

Comment: It was setup a couple months ago.  Yep, I went through the process where you pick which type of page it is, etc

Comment: Following up very late but is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try navigating directly to this URL, putting your page's ID in the place of `YOUR_ID_HERE`. Might allow you access to the other pages.

```
https://www.facebook.com/pages/edit/?id=YOUR_ID_HERE&sk=basic
```

If you still can't, try opening a support ticket here: http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=pages_bug